# How to use explode function in PHP?

Tags: php

- I want to spit my string in to 2 pieces, I know that I have to use `explode` function in PHP.
- Then I want to apply `strtolower` to my first element, and apply `strtoupper` for my last element, I just could figure it out where is the pieces are stored after splitting them ?

> What I have tried ?

```
            // $value[0] = "8000297C-1360598144"; 

            echo $value[0] . "<br>";
            dd(explode('-', $value[0]));

            echo "<br>";
```

Comment: `$split = explode('-', $value[0]); var_dump($split);`

Comment: `$foo = explode('-', $value[0]); $part1 = strtolower($foo[0]); $part2 = strtoupper($foo[1]);`. What are you asking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "pieces" are not stored, but returned as the return value:

```
echo $value[0] . "<br>";
$pieces = explode('-', $value[0]);
echo strtolower($pieces[0]);
echo "<br>";
echo strtoupper($pieces[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$value[0] = "8000297C-1360598144";
$value[0] = explode("-",$value[0]);
$value[0][0] = strtolower($value[0][0]);
$value[0][1] = strtoupper($value[0][1]);
```

From this, `print_r($value);` will output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8000297c
            [1] => 1360598144
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// $value[0] = "8000297C-1360598144"; 
echo $value[0] . "<br>";
$elements = explode('-', $value[0]);
//
$elementzero = isset($elements[0]) ? $elements[0] : null;
$elementone = isset($elements[1]) ? $elements[1] : null; 
echo strtolower($elementzero);
echo strtoupper($elementone);
```

If delimiter is an empty string (""), explode() will return FALSE. If delimiter contains a value that is not contained in string and a negative limit is used, then an empty array will be returned, otherwise an array containing string will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this:

```
$value[0] = "8000297C-1360598144";
list($first, $second) = explode('-', $value[0]);
echo strtolower($first) . PHP_EOL;
echo strtoupper($second) . PHP_EOL;
```

Best,

Comment: I learned so much from this post. Thank you guys so much for sharing your knowledge.