# How to filter timeslot

Tags: php

I have a code like this that outputs the time slots in a list.

```
<?php
    $timesolts = timeslots($duration, $cleanup, $start, $end);
    foreach ($timesolts as $ts) {
?>
        <button disabled type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" style="margin-bottom:5px; font-size: 12px;" data-timeslot="<?php echo $ts; ?>" >
            <?php echo $ts; ?>
        </button>
<?php } ?>
```

> 08:00-08:30

> 09:00-09:30

> 10:00-10:30

There is a need to get only the start time, how to get only the start time from this code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use explode function in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28345829/how-to-use-explode-function-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You may use explode to get the start time , specifying hyphen as delimiter

```
$st = explode("-", $ts);
// then use $st[0];
```

Hence change

```
 $timesolts = timeslots($duration, $cleanup, $start, $end);
            foreach ($timesolts as $ts) {
            ?>
             <button disabled type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" style="margin-bottom:5px; font-size: 12px;" data-timeslot="<?php echo $ts; ?>" ><?php echo $ts; ?></button>
            <?}?>
```

to

```
 $timesolts = timeslots($duration, $cleanup, $start, $end);
            foreach ($timesolts as $ts) {
            $st = explode("-", $ts);
            ?>
             <button disabled type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" style="margin-bottom:5px; font-size: 12px;" data-timeslot="<?php echo $st[0]; ?>" ><?php echo $st[0]; ?></button>
            <?}?>
```